# problem with text added to pdf under Xournal after exporting to pdf

Tags: pdf

Under Xournal, I add some text to a pdf file, and then I export to a pdf file. In the exported pdf file, the text I added is shown correctly, and selectable, but when I copy and paste the selected text out to a text editor, it is not the same text I added.

For example, under Xournal, I add `locking` to a pdf file, and in the exported pdf file, when I select the text and copy and paste it into a text editor, the text is  `PSGOMRK`.

I wonder if it is a bug of Xournal?

How can I make the selected text from the exported pdf file the same as the text I added under Xournal?

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, and the version of Xournal is 0.4.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a fairly old bug with [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/). I found this thread describing the exact same issue as well, titled: "[copy text from pdf problem (xournal)](http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=22492). Using the latest version (0.47), I was able to reproduce the issue as well.

[image: ss of xournal]

I then exported the annoted PDF as a new PDF and then copied the annotated string "This is some extra text." and attempted to paste it in `vim`. Doing so I got this string: `8LMW MW WSQI I\XVE XI\X`.

I can continuously repeat this problem over and over. It's definitely an issue with the annotation done by Xournal. The pre-existing text, `PDF 3` worked fine when I copy and pasted it.

#### Alternative?

You might want to try using [Okular](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html) which can also annotate PDF files.

[image: ss of okular]

Comment: Thanks! (1) Do you recommend other applications for annotating pdf files without the problem? (2) I posted a message on their SourceForge forum.

Comment: @Tim - see update.

Comment: Thanks! In Okular, I found that after I click one of those review tools and apply it to the text, if I want to apply the same tool to other places in the text, I have to click the tool again. Is it possible that once I click a review tool, I can apply it many times till I decide to change the tool?

Comment: @Tim - We're starting to meander away from your original Q. Can you ask this as a separate Q since you're now asking about usability for Okular? Also if your original Q was answered can you mark this as the accepted A so others know your original issue's been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**PART SOLUTION**

You can't fix **.pdf** file after you have exported it from the **.xoj** file. But if you still have **.xoj** file you can still do something..

Files of type **.xoj** depend on the **.pdf** files. So if you move or rename **.pdf** files they won't be found once you open **.xoj** file with Xournal. And Xournal will luckily prompt you to tell it to choose another **.pdf** file and this is your chance. Choose the right one and then for export don't use "**export as PDF**" but "**print/print to file**".

---

**ALTERNATIVE**

Best alternative at the moment is Master PDF editor. I use Arch Linux and here is our package for [GTK](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/masterpdfeditor/) and [QT5](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/masterpdfeditor-qt5/).