# Xournal: Added Text is Truncated in Resultant PDF

Tags: pdf, xournal

**Xournal** version 0.4.8.

**PROBLEM:** Under certain conditions, text added to an existing PDF file is truncated when the modified PDF is then printed to file.

**RECREATION:** Create a PDF file (I did same by using **LibreOffice** (version  4.3.3.2) to create a short, two-line PDF file using the `File -> Export as PDF...` option.  Open said newly-created PDF file using **Xournal**. Input the following text annotation in a single line:

`FYI, it was obvious, nine months later, when I told Zoey about this abazz`

(Sorry to be so specific about the added text, but there are only specific text strings that seem to expose this problem...)

Create a PDF using Xournal (using **Xournal**'s `File -> Print` or `File -> Export to PDF` options). Open resultant PDF using **Evince** (version 3.14.1), and...

...the text I added using **Xournal** is truncated, with ONLY the trailing "z" being displayed!

**PROPOSED SOLUTION:** I did lots of research and have posted my proposed workarounds below. Please post any "solutions" you know about. The best one will get my vote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two workarounds that work for me:

1. Shorten the line(s) of said added (annotated) text.
2. If **#1** is unacceptable to you, back on the **Xournal** page, go to the `Options` menu and select the `Legacy PDF Export` option. Then, create the desired, duly annotated PDF file using **Xournal**'s `File -> Export to PDF` option.

End of problem...

A note of caution, however, for option **#2**: Creating a PDF in this fashion reincarnates the hoary old bug mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122853/144299).